# In ASP.NET MVC 2 - How do I get Route Values into my navigation controller so I can highlight the current link?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I'm trying to get the current Route into my navigation controller so I can run comparisons as the navigation menu data is populated.

My Links object is like this:

```
public class StreamNavLinks
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In the master page, I'm trying to pass the current route to the nav controller like this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction(
    "MenuOfStreamEntries", // action
    "Nav", // controller
    new { // parameters for action
        currentStreamUrl = "Blog", 
        currentRoute = ViewContext.RouteData } // get route data to compare in controller
); %>
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to get any of the data out of `currentRoute`. What is the best technique for getting the values out or `currentRoute`?

I've tried syntax like this:

```
 currentRoute.Values.routevaluename
```

and

```
 currentRoute.Values[0]
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

### Edit

I have also tried placing this code into the action of the navigation controller:

```
var current = RouteData["streamUrl"];
```

and

```
var current = this.RouteData["streamUrl"];
```

Both versions give me this error:

> Error  1   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of >type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteData'  C:\pathtocontroller\NavController.cs    25  27

### Edit 2

It also might be helpful to know the route values that I'm trying to match against:

```
        routes.MapRoute(null, "", // Only matches the empty URL (i.e. ~/)
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Stream",
                            action = "Entry",
                            streamUrl = "Pages",
                            entryUrl = "HomePage"
                        }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{streamUrl}/{entryUrl}", // matches ~/Pages/HomePage
                        new { controller = "Stream", action = "Entry" }
        );
```

So, ultimately mydomain.com/blog/blogentry1 would map to the same controller/action as mydomain.com/pages/welcome. I'm not looking for the controller value or the action value, rather I'm looking for streamUrl value and EntryUrl value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to pass route data to a controller because the controller already has knowledge of it via the [`RouteData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.routedata.aspx) property:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    // You could use this.RouteData here
    ...
}
```

Now if you want to pass some simple arguments like current action that was used to render the view you could do this:

```
<%= Html.RenderAction(
    "MenuOfStreamEntries",
    "Nav",
    new {
        currentStreamUrl = "Blog", 
        currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"],
        currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
    }
); %>
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Nav(string currentAction, string currentController) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Am I doning this right in the controller? `var current =  this.RouteData["streamUrl"];` doesn't compile.

Comment: Should be `RouteData.Values["streamUrl"]`

Comment: @Darin - I got the same error with that syntax. Please see edited question above.

Comment: In your Edit you are trying `RouteData["streamUrl"];` while I suggested you `RouteData.Values["streamUrl"]`. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Darin - the devil's in the details. lol I'm playing with it again now.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [this good article](http://geekswithblogs.net/bdiaz/archive/2010/04/09/handy-asp.net-mvc-2-extension-methods-ndash-where-am-i.aspx).

Create a custom extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText,
        String actionName, String controllerName)
    {
        var tag = new TagBuilder("li");

        if ( htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext
            .IsCurrentRoute(null, controllerName, actionName) )
        {
            tag.AddCssClass("selected");
        }

        tag.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToString();

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

Your HTML markup:

```
<div id="menucontainer">

    <ul id="menu">
        <%= Html.ActionMenuItem("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
        <%= Html.ActionMenuItem("About", "About", "Home") %>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<div id="menucontainer">

    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample method we wrote for doing something similar.

```
public static bool IsCurrentAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, string controllerName)
{
  string currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
  string currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

  return currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && currentActionName.Equals(actionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: This is cool. I might switch my navigation code to do something more like this.

Comment: did not show how to use IsCurrentAction() function. provide the usage too.