# How to get query string parameter from MVC Razor markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to check the URL parameter in my Razor markup. For example, how do I do something like this:

```
<div id="wrap" class="@{if (URL "IFRAME" PARAMETER EQUALS 1) iframe-page}">
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

[Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660329/in-asp-net-mvc-2-how-do-i-get-route-values-into-my-navigation-controller-so-i)

```
<div id="wrap" class=' @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["iframe"] == 1 ? /*do sth*/ : /*do sth else*/')> </div>
```

**EDIT 01-10-2014:**
Since this question is so popular this answer has been improved.

The example above will only get the values from `RouteData`, so only from the querystrings which are caught by some registered route. To get the querystring value you have to get to the current `HttpRequest`. Fastest way is by calling (as TruMan pointed out) `Request.Querystring' so the answer should be:

```
<div id="wrap" class=' @(Request.QueryString["iframe"] == 1 ? /*do sth*/ : /*do sth else*/')> </div>
```

You can also check [RouteValues vs QueryString MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090546/routevalues-vs-querystring-mvc/14092478#14092478)

**EDIT 03-05-2019:**
Above solution is working for *.NET Framework.* 
As others pointed out if you would like to get query string value in *.NET Core* you have to use `Query` object from `Context.Request` path. So it would be:

```
<div id="wrap" class=' @(Context.Request.Query["iframe"] == new StringValues("1") ? /*do sth*/ : /*do sth else*/')> </div>
```

Please notice I am using `StringValues("1")` in the statement because `Query` returns `StringValues` struct instead of pure `string`. That's cleanes way for this scenerio which I've found.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. This worked: <div id="wrap" class="@(Request.QueryString["iframe"] == "1" ? "iframe" : string.Empty)">

Comment: I would add @TruMan1 's comment to your answer. In my case the values weren't in the route data (using nop-commerce) but were accessible via the request.

Comment: To clarify - you'd use Request.QueryString for example if the view is being displayed as a consequence of a redirect

Comment: You might want to add that beginning with [.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.1) you need to change `Context` to `HttpContext`

Comment: That's working..Thanks.    @Context.Request.Query["iframe"]

Comment: Going back to update multiple times is appreciated. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using .net core 2.0 this would be:

```
Context.Request.Query["id"]
```

**Sample usage:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Query",new {parm1=Context.Request.Query["queryparm1"]})">GO</a>
```

Comment: This gives 'The name Context does not exist in the current context'. Just using Request.Query["queryparm1"] works though.

Comment: @x5657 you should post your comment as an answer, as it was the only solution that really worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

It was suggested to post this as an answer, because some other answers are giving errors like 'The name Context does not exist in the current context'.

Just using the following works:

```
Request.Query["queryparm1"]
```

Sample usage:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Query",new {parm1=Request.Query["queryparm1"]})">GO</a>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me but this did: Request.QueryString

Answer (score 11):

**for ASP.NET Core 5.0**

You can get query parameters by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into the Razor page. And get the value of any parameter with `Request.Query` object.

Sample URL => https://localhost:44326/?MyParam=MyValue

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<span>@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["MyParam"][0]</span>
```

Note that there maybe several query parameters with the same name therefore the values are stored in a collection.

Comment: don't forget to add nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

Comment: this worked for me even without Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http in .net core 7.0 core web api

Answer (score 10):

Noneof the answers worked for me, I was getting "'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'Query'", but this did work:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["index"]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think a more elegant solution is to use the controller and the ViewData dictionary:

```
//Controller:
public ActionResult Action(int IFRAME)
    {
        ViewData["IsIframe"] = IFRAME == 1;
        return View();
    }

//view
@{
    string classToUse = (bool)ViewData["IsIframe"] ? "iframe-page" : "";
   <div id="wrap" class='@classToUse'></div>
 }
```

Comment: This view is shared across many controllers. I think this would get messy doing it like this instead of putting the logic directly in the Razor markup. Also I anticipate I may have to do this in partial views as well.

Comment: A more elegant solution is to return it as part of a ViewModel 

`return View(new SomeViewModel{
    IsIFrame = IFrame
});`

Answer (score 1):

For Asp.net Core 2

```
ViewContext.ModelState["id"].AttemptedValue
```

Comment: I'll just add that although it says `AttempValue` - if the paramter does not exist in the query string you will get an exception so you should first check: `@if (ViewContext.ModelState["id"] != null)...`