# How to get url parameter value of current route in view in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For example I am on page `http://localhost:1338/category/category1?view=list&min-price=0&max-price=100`

And in my view I want to render some form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary { { /*this is poblem place*/ } }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <!--Render some controls-->
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

What I want is to get `view` parameter value from current page link to use it for constructing form get request. I tried `@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary { { "view", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["view"] } }, FormMethod.Get))` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should still have access to the Request object from within the view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(
    "Action", 
    "Controller", 
    new RouteValueDictionary { 
        { "view", Request.QueryString["view"] } }, FormMethod.Get))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was locking for.

Answer (score 19):

I've found the solution [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248064/how-to-get-query-string-parameter-from-mvc-razor-markup)

```
@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["view"])
```

Comment: This worked with ROUTE PARAM which is what I needed. ```Request.Params["paramName"]``` did **NOT** work with ROUTE PARAM.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access Request object directly in ASP .NET Core. Here is a way to do it.

```
@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["view"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From an MVC perspective, you would want to pass the value from the controller into the page e.g.

```
public ActionResult ViewCategory(int categoryId, string view)
{
    ViewBag.ViewType = view;
    return View();
}
```

Then in your view you an access `@ViewBag.ViewType`, you will need to cast it to a string though as it will by default be `object` (`ViewBag` is a dynamic object).