# RouteValues vs QueryString MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Whats the differences between `QueryString` in `Request` and `RouteData.Values` ?

Can we use them instead ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RouteValues are gathered from querystring only if are defined in global.asax, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Example", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{inRouteValues}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

will catch inRouteValues from `yourdomain/testController/testAction/14/myTestValue`
where `RouteData.Values["inRouteValues"]` will be string with value "myTestValue". 
 But if you will build URL like `yourdomain/testController/testAction/14?inRouteValues=myTestValue` it won't get it. So difference is that `RouteData.Values` will get only values from URLs that match `RouteCollection`from your global.asax and `QueryString` will catch every value from your querystring if it matches variable name.