# The name Request doesnt exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, view, request

I have simple form for Login page. However it is giving me error saying Request doesnt exist in that context. How do I fix it?

```
model Phishing.Models.PersonClass
    

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="username" name="UserName" />
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" name="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Core you have to use Query object from Context.Request path. So it would be:

```
Context.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"]
```

look at: [How to get query string parameter from MVC Razor markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248064/how-to-get-query-string-parameter-from-mvc-razor-markup)