# Create a toggleable image button in MVC4 web grid

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a "Lock"/"Unlock" button/link that a user can click in a grid listing user accounts using MVC4. In WebForms, this is a relatively simple task of putting an ImageButton into the grid template for the column and connecting it to the Command event for that button and then chaning the "Lock"/"Unlock" text displayed against that user. But I cannot seem to quite figure out how to do this in MVC4. Or at least not without jumping through quite a few hoops to get ajax/jquery to play nice with each user in the grid.

Currently I have the grid listing the users registered on the system and this grid is correctly displaying. The grid displays in a simple view and the controller returns a model with a property of `Users`. This property in turn is a list of `UserInfo` objects with basic user details such as UserName, Name and IsActive.

I have tried playing around with using Html.RenderAction to call a dedicated action called Lock that does the task but kept getting errors trying to pass in the user details to the controller ([In ASP.NET MVC 2 - How do I get Route Values into my navigation controller so I can highlight the current link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660329/in-asp-net-mvc-2-how-do-i-get-route-values-into-my-navigation-controller-so-i) - didn't work for me).

Likewise, I tried creating a partial view but again, kept getting errors ([Html.RenderPartial giving me strange overload error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435893/html-renderpartial-giving-me-strange-overload-error) and no, it didn't work for me either).

I've been trawling through SO researching these individual issues and alternative methods of doing what I want to do for a day now and I'm no closer to succeedign in this task.

Is there a simple way of doing what I describe? Do I have to write out individually numbered element tags for each user row to attach jquery functions to?

*UPDATE*
Code generating the grid;

```
if (Model != null && Model.Users != null && Model.Users.Count > 0)
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                User
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Lock/Unlock
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (UserInfoModel user in Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(user.UserName, "Edit", new { id = user.PersonID })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => user.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @*@Html.Action("Lock", new { personID = user.PersonID, isLocked = null as bool?})*@
                    @*@{ Html.Render("_Lock", new { personID = user.PersonID, isLocked = null as bool? }); }*@
                    @Html.ActionLink("Lock", "Lock", new { personID = user.PersonID, lockAccount = user.IsActive })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

The controller code attempt;

```
[Authorize(Roles = LMSRoles.Administrators)]
public ActionResult Lock(int personID, bool lockAccount)
{
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);// PartialView("_Lock");
}
```

Comment: how are you creating the grid? show us some code. Usually, I would add a class to each button/links on the grid and use jquery selector to handle the `click` event. Personally, I feel more confirtable with this rather than the traditional approach :-)

Comment: @NaveenBhat I have added the code generating the grid. I've left in the two (now commented out), previous attempts to get it to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. As soon as you click on the link `Lock`, it should redirect to the action `Lock` (if the user is authorized with the role `Administrators`).

It seem that you would rather want to do an ajax request. In that case, I prefer to use `jquery` as I said in the comments earlier.

In-order to do that, alter your `ActionLink` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Lock", "Lock", 
     new { personID = user.PersonID, lockAccount = user.IsActive }, 
     new { @class="lock" }) // Add a dummy css class 'lock'
```

Write the below script, inside **document's ready** event handler:

```
// Register click handler for any element with the class 'lock' (works only if the element an 'a' tag).
$('.lock').click(function (e) {
    // Prevent the default functionality.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do the get ajax request (you can do post as well, but not required in this case).
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href'), // Take the URL from link's href
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            // Display loading image
        },
        success: function (result) {
            // Handle the response here. Ex: Inform the user that, lock operation is succeeded.
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Hide loading image.
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Handle error.
        }
    });

});
```

The code is simple & self-explanatory but still I put detailed comments, assuming that `jquery` is new for you.

PS: Don't forget to include `jquery` file, before you use this script.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I needed but it sent me down the right path